# Generating array-agg(...)s in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, array-agg

Using Postgres 10 I have tables representing 'units', the 'group' to which each unit belongs, and the 'distance' between each pair of units.

I now want a group-to-group distance table that aggregates all the unit-to-unit distances for each pair of groups - i.e. an aggregate array of the distances from all the units in one group to all the units in the other group.

What I have

```
  'units'          'unit_distances'
  id | group       this_unit_id | that_unit_id | distance      
  ----------       --------------------------------------
  1  |   1            1         |   2          | d_12
  2  |   1            1         |   3          | d_13
  3  |   2            1         |   4          | d_14
  4  |   3            2         |   3          | d_23
...  | ...          ...         | ...          |  ...
```

What I want

```
'group_distances'
this_group_id | that_group_id | all_distances
---------------------------------------------------
  1            |   2          | {d_13, d_23}
  1            |   3          | {d_14, d_24}
  2            |   3          | {d_34}
...            | ...          | {..., ...
```

I'm not sure how to return all such arrays for all group-group pairings and generate the table depicted above. At the moment I can only get these arrays by defining the sites individually (as x and y below).

```
with dist as (
    select      distance 
    from        unit_distances
    inner join  units
    on          unit_distances.this_unit_id = units.id
    WHERE       units.group = x
intersect
    select      distance 
    from        unit_distances
    inner join  units
    on          unit_distances.that_unit_id = units.id
    WHERE       units.group = y)

select  array_agg(distance) from dist;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is just two joins to get the groups and an aggregation for the distances:

```
select u1.group, u2.group, array_agg(ud.distance) as all_distances
from unit_distances ud join
     units u1
     on ud.this_unit_id = u1.id join
     units u2
     on ud.that_unit_id = u2.id
group by u1.group, u2.group;
```